# Who were the first fictional TV characters labeled as jarheads in Futurama?

Tags: futurama

We've enjoyed seeing the US Presidents and other real life celebrities in the New New York Head Museum. Who was/were the first fictional TV character(s) from a different show given a nod as labeled [head jars](http://theinfosphere.org/Head_Jars) on Futurama? The Star Trek cast appeared as actors, not characters. I'm looking for labeled names on the headjars of fictional characters.

Comment: Not true. The Star Trek TOS cast appeared as themselves, forced to replay their roles by Melllvar ad infinitum. ... unless the actual Star Trek characters were introduced in a very recent episode I haven't seen yet.

Comment: @bitmask Sorry. +1. I wrote that example bass about ackwards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having had a flick through the head jar episodes, Space Pilot 3000 does not have any named fictional characters.  There are a lot of heads without nameplates present.

The earliest I can definitely confirm a fictional head appears is in All The Presidents' Heads (Season 6, Episode 20) - [Sharon Anders](http://theinfosphere.org/Sharon_Anders%27_head) is the first to appear at 2:46 into the episode.  Several more appear later in that episode, including (later) Amelia Pond (the first fictional TV character, as per your question, at 3:11) and Inara Serra (4:04).

The only confirmable fictional un-nameplated head in an earlier episode that I've found is [Eric Cartman](http://theinfosphere.org/Eric_Cartman%27s_head), who was in Bender's Big Score.

Answer (score 2):

The [infosphere](http://theinfosphere.org/Head_Museum#Fictional_characters_seen_in_the_museum) lists five fictional characters to have appeared in the Head Museum, the first non-Groening character seems to be the head of Eric Cartman appearing in the first film, while the very first fictional character to appear in Futurama alltogether is the head of [Apu Nahasapeemapetilon](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Apu_Nahasapeemapetilon%27s_head), who apparently already appears in the very first episode ([Space Pilot 3000](http://theinfosphere.org/Space_Pilot_3000)).

I highly doubt that a head is seen previously, outside the head museum, as the heads in jars are introduced when Fry enters the museum, and they only visit it once during that episode.

Comment: Looking at the picture on http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Apu_Nahasapeemapetilon%27s_head, it doesn't really look like http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_-1GM7VDiWKE/S_nKPD3cvyI/AAAAAAAAB0M/9uXnh8b05mY/s1600/Apu+Nahasapeemapetilon.gif and it also doesn't have a nameplate.